# Default Protostar top navigation is not horizontal (class nav-pills is missing)

Tags: templates

I'm playing around with the default Protostar template that comes with Joomla 3. I took my online site offline and additionally, installed a local webserver for testing. When I use the default Protostar template, I cannot get the top navigation in horizontal direction. It looks like this:

> [image]

On my local site, everything works fine. Using Chrome dev tools revealed that on my online site there is a missing `class` specifier in the navigation menu. The list starts like this:

```
<ul class="nav menu jmoddiv" data-jmodediturl=...
```

In my local installation, there is an additinal `nav-pills` entry there. When I add this (with the dev-tools) `nav-pills`, the navigation looks fine.

While my local site was a fresh install, my online site was updated from 2.5. I uninstalled the Protostar template of the online site, packed the local template and re-installed it; without success.

Is there anything I'm doing obviously wrong?

---

Online Joomla information

[image]

Local Joomla information

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your online site, login to the backend, go to the **Module Manager** and open the **Menu** module. There will be a field called **Module Class Suffix** under the **Advanced** tab. In here, type in :

```
nav-pills
```

Make sure there is a space before the value.

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh man, now I see it. You don't want to know for how long I have compared settings... haven't seen the difference there. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As Lodder said but it was **Menu Class Suffix** not **Module Class Suffix** field that fixed it for me.